# signalR python client

Tags: python, websocket, signalr

Is there a serviseR (ASP .NET CORE 2.0) client for python?

I've found [signal  library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/signalr-client/0.0.7)  but it's too old, and doesn't working with my signalR server (**Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.0.0-alpha2-final"**) because [this python library uses '/negotiate' method, which is not used in new versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdXmH.png).